# Can I extend the core helpers within a package in Code Igniter?

Tags: codeigniter, package, helper, hmvc, extending

I'm building my own base to use on multiple sites that I will be building. And I've made a package for that. But I want to extend the CI helpers in that package (not in the app) - helpers such as `url_helper`, `html_helper` etc.

I've put a config folder (although I don't really understant what it does) in the package folder and a config file in it (so structure is `packages/app_package/config/config.php`).

I've put the `$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'app_';` (different from the application one preferably) and still not loading the helpers `app_url_helper` etc

Did anybody do that?

Comment: better to keep this config default don't change it, if its not working may be bug

Comment: Which config? And please define what you mean by "default".

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [CodeIgniter Helpers](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html). Specifically the section labelled **"Extending" Helpers**.

I'm not quite sure what you mean by:

> I've put a config folder (although I don't really understant what it
>   does) in the package folder and a config file in it (so structure is
>   packages/app_package/config/config.php).

You're not required to 'create' any config folders or files at all. The config file already exists and is located in `application/config/config.php` of your CodeIgniter project. The Class Extension Prefix is located ~ line 110 (version dependent). Set it to `_app`

Now create `app_url_helper.php` and `app_html_helper.php` in `application/helpers` and away you go.

Comment: I've clearly stated in the title and in the post "within a package".